# Submit an input at each character entry

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to create a form in which the submit button is disabled until the text matches my conditions. And I'd like to constantly (each time a character is typed) check the text, instead of having to create a button that will activate another one.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery and keyup to detect every time that the user type something here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/82sTJ/253/

```
<input type="text" id="text">
<button type="submit" disabled id="submitButton">
Submit
</button>

var condition = "good";
$('#text').keyup(function(event) {
   if($('#text').val() == condition) {       
     $("#submitButton").prop('disabled', false);
   }else{
     $("#submitButton").prop('disabled', true);
   }
});
```

Here is the alternative way using input suggested by Rob:

```
var condition = "good";
$('#text').on("input", function(event) {
   if($('#text').val() == condition) {       
     $("#submitButton").prop('disabled', false);
   }else{
     $("#submitButton").prop('disabled', true);
   }
});
```

Also you can use something like vue.js or angular to check the value in real time.

*Edited

Comment: I think .input is much better choice since it would fire also on paste.